# Xamarin.Forms Bindable Picker

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker, bindable

I have 2 pickers. On changing any value in first picker the second picker elements should change. My issue is on `selectIndexchanged()` of first picker I am clearing secondpicker list by `picker2.items.clear()`. But if i select a value in second picker and then change first picker index on executing `clear()` it is showing exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Answer (score 1):

I think that might be happening because the `Picker.SelectedIndex` is getting set to say 5 for example but the number of items in the `Picker` is after being cleared 0. Try setting the `Picker.SelectedIndex` to 0 or -1 before clearing the items out.